# I want to push each entry of the hiddenarray to the uiarray at a specific interval of time using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I want to push each entry of the hiddenarray to the uiarray at a specific interval of time using javascript

```js
const hiddenArray = props.data;
const uiArray = [];
setInterval(() => {
  uiArray.push({
    hiddenArray
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(uiArray));
}, 2000);
```

I tried implementing using settimeout but it is not working

Comment: Before asking question, it may be beneficial to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the various pages in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), particularly [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: The question **title** should be a concise description of the issue. The question **code** should be formatted code in the question. The code should include enough context to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### set and remove interval inside an useEffect

initializing state with first 3 items of hiddenArray

replace it with `[]` if initialization is not required

```
const [uiArray, setUiArray] = useState(hiddenArray.slice(0, 3));
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      // after every 2 seconds push 3 entries
      setUiArray((prevState) => [
        ...prevState,
        ...hiddenArray.slice(prevState.length, prevState.length + 3)
      ]);
    }, 2000);

    // clear interval
    if (uiArray.length >= hiddenArray.length) {
      console.log("cleared");
      clearInterval(interval);
    }

    // clear interval on unmount
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [uiArray]);
```

Check this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sof-q-75890749-if8z96?file=/src/App.js) for working demo